Sparse regular spiral underextrusion
My print has a regular spiral underextrusion which crosses layers (see attached photo). It is likely not a slicer issue since multiple prints of the same model have the spiral pattern in different locations. In particular the underextrusion is not along the Z seam (which follows the sharpest edges in the model).
Elegoo Neptune 3 Pro, Ziro matte tri-color filament, 195 °C, very slow print speed.


What is the layer height and the nozzle diameter? It looks like you Z-axis is catching something, cable/Bowden tube?

It almost looks like topographical elevation lines on a map, but it crosses layer lines which is unusual.  Can you post a picture of the whole printer?  Or even watch the printer as it prints through one of these lines ?  Does a small test print show the issue?

Try turning off power-loss resume.
The pattern of blobbing and underextrusion here looks a lot like print issues generated by that particular feature.  Assuming you're printing from an SD card, print resume must write to that SD card data about how far through the print the printer has gone, and this periodic write can cause the printer to stutter or stop periodically if the gcode cache empties while it is writing and can't read the next line.  Alternatively, a faster SD card, or printing from USB may also solve the problem (but require purchasing new equipment or changing your setup).

really unlikely

Start with increasing the temperature: 195 °C is the bare minimum print temperature (for PLA, for silky filaments it should be even higher) so you get terrible layer adhesion. Maybe this model is more prone to warping so you finally found out that layer adhesion matters.
Go to 205 °C as very minimum for that filament, and 215 °C would be even better.
Personally I print silky filament at 225-230 °C, but my printer is faster so I need more than usual.
